# inbuilt save button text

Tags: iphone

I want to change here title of button can i change   by default it is coming 'save' can it be changed

```
UIBarButtonItem *dowButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
                                                                           target:self action:@selector(download)];
```

**strong text**

Comment: Please have a look at all your questions. If somebody helps you with a good answer, click on the top-arrow. Honor the best answer with a click on the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Create an own `UIBarButtonItem` instead of using the `UIBarButtonSystemItemSave`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *dowButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(download)] autorelease];
```

This will helps you :-)

Comment: @user642472:The above answer is useful for u ah?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the method

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```